# Command Error : ( MongoServerError: bad auth : Authentication failed )

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb

Really I am trying to do a mongoose connection from Mongo Atlas. I think that I have a cluster problem. Please check the code and give me an answer.

```js
//db connection
const uri = `mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@cluster0.qyrzo.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1 });

console.log('db connect');
```

Comment: A very common thing you see with people using Mongo Atlas their first few times is that they miss that you MUST whitelist your client's IP in their settings or there will be a bad auth. 

Log in to mongo atlas dashboard and look through the options carefully. (They actually mention it several times during setup, but we programmers just love to skip through those things as fast as humanly possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the [mongoose library](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html)

you can try using a standard declaration

```
    mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@cluster0.qyrzo.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority");
```

if you are on latest version of mongoose you don't need to add the optional parametes

> { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1 }

but you can add it makes no difference

```
    mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://${process.env.DB_USER}:${process.env.DB_PASSWORD}@cluster0.qyrzo.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority", { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, serverApi: ServerApiVersion.v1 });
```